# Change dynamic buttons text with textbox

Tags: c#, button, dynamic, text

Let me tell you what I want to do.

1.there are two button in my form.One of them let button when I click it.Another button finish to create button.

```
bool active = false;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        active = true;

    }
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        active = false;
    }
```

2.I will create button with mousedown event I want to set location of this buttons with coordinate like this.

```
Button button_create;

private void frm_tr_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (active)
        {
            button_create = new Button();
            button_create.Location = new Point(e.X + 5, e.Y - 15);
            button_create.Size = new Size(75, 30);
            button_create.Text = "Button";
            this.Controls.Add(button_create);

            button_create.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(button_create_MouseClick);

        }
    }
```

3.I started mouseclickevent of my created button.When I click this created button I will create new form textbox and button.

```
TextBox button_text;
void button_create_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Form frm = new Form();
        frm.Show();

        button_text = new TextBox();

        Button accept = new Button();
        accept.Location = new Point(frm.Width / 2, frm.Height / 2);

        frm.Controls.Add(button_text);
        frm.Controls.Add(accept);

        accept.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(accept_MouseClick);

    }
```

4.I started mouseclickevent of my last created button.I want to change text of my first created button.

```
  void accept_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        button_create.Text = button_text.Text;
    }
```

5.I will click button1 and I click anywhere of this form new button will create and I also click button2 to finish create new button.I can change my created button with textbox but 
If I click button1 and I create a new one button I cant change text of previous created button How can I do that?

Comment: You have to create an array of buttons. So that you can control every each of them seperately

Comment: @AlexJolig I think I should create List but I dont know how to do

Comment: Let's see if i got this straight. You want to keep a reference to the very first created button at any time? And you only need to change the text of the first button? If so, just detect when you have created the first button and store that in a reference which you don't change. If on the other hand you need to be able to edit any button text using a textbox you would need to have some sort of selection capability. One thing that could help you there is lambda expressions and subscribing/unsubscribing the click events. But your question is a bit vague for me.